# Resolving duplicate object change notifications

Tags: c++, qt, notifications

The following problem is proving quite hard for me to find a neat solution to.

Let's say I have the following objects in C++ pseudocode:

```
// Class A simply holds a collection of properties.
class A
{
    // Some properties
};

// Class B could hold a bounded number of A& references.
// The referenced A objects are not owned by B.
class B
{
    A& m_a0;
    A& m_a1;

    // Some other properties
};

// Class C could hold an unbounded number of A& references.
// The referenced A objects are not owned by C.
class C
{
    List<A&> m_aList;

    // Some other properties
};

// Class D holds lists of objects.
// The objects are owned by D.
// The A references held by objects of type B or C
// refer to instances of A objects that class D owns
// (ie. entries in m_aList).
class D
{
    List<A> m_aList;
    List<B> m_bList;
    List<C> m_cList;

    // Some other properties
};
```

Each object has the ability to send a notification on certain events; in my usage context, this is a Qt C++ "signal" that other objects can respond to. The following properties hold:

- *A* object emits a change notification when any of its properties are changed.
- *B* object emits a change notification if it receives one from either of its referenced *A* objects, or if any other of its own properties change.
- *C* object emits a change notification if it receives one from any of its referenced *A* objects, or if any other of its own properties change.
- *D* object emits a change notification if it receives one from any object in m_bList or m_cList, or if any other of its own properties change.

My problem occurs when the following setup exists:

- An instance of *D*, "**d0**", holds some number of *A*, *B* and *C* objects.
- There exist a *B* object "**b0**" and a *C* object "**c0**" such that they have at least one *A&*, "**a0**", in common.
- A property on **a0** is changed; **a0** sends a change notification.
- Since **a0** is a referenced component of both **b0** and **c0**, **b0** and **c0** both send change notifications.
- **d0** receives both of these consecutive notifications and so sends two of its own change notifications, even though there has only been one overall change in the state of **d0**.

Since in reality I am acting upon the change notification from *D* objects in order to rebuild their visual representation in 3D, responding to a *D* change notification is costly and so the above situation is both inaccurate and inefficient in the context of the application.

The following approaches I have considered are not viable:

- Restricting all access to *A* objects through mutator methods in *D*, so that if a property on an *A* object is changed then the mutator method sends the *D* object notification once only. This is not viable because it may be useful to pass around a reference to an *A* object, and when the *A* reference is modified externally then the *D* change notification should still be sent. This method might also require separate mutator methods for each and every property in *A*, which would be a nightmare to maintain.
- Only send a *D* change notification when an *A* notification is received and ignore notifications from *B* and *C* objects. This is not viable because *B* or *C* objects may have other internal properties which would cause a change notification to be fired, and in this case *D* would still need to send its own notification in response.

Is there a scalable solution to this problem? I would like to achieve behaviour where, for each individual change of a single property of a component belonging to *D*, *D* would fire one change notification.

Comment: I don't know whether this is an efficient one or not. try to send a random number with A change signal. it will be forwarded ahead to B changed->C changed -> D changed.
now define one integer in class D. that will store the random number when first D change event is generated. next time it will check that random number first and if random number is same do nothing. this checking will be done in slot connected to the signal of D changed event.

Comment: This is also something I considered; it might work OK if the duplicate signals were guaranteed to be sent consecutively, as you'd only need to store the most recent ID that came with the signal. I think this is the case given what I've put above, but I'll make sure.

Comment: try to do it in a small demo first. if it works as we are expecting. then no worries. lets see.All the Best.